# Draw only border of a rounded rectangle inside a circle

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using the extended_image library to allow users to crop their images. I have a listview showing crop options (i.e. 4:3, 3:4, 16:9 etc.). I have successfully created each item of the listview using Painter.

[image]

As you can see the aspect ratios are being drawn in the circles. Although this is great, I only want the outline of these rounded rectangles and not the fill. So how do I just get the borders?

My Code:

```html
final Path path = Path();
    path.fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
    path.addOval(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(43, 30),
        radius: 30.0,
      ),
    );
    path.addRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        getDestinationRect(
          rect: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 15.0,
            bottom: 30.0,
            left: 30.0,
            right: 30.0,
          ).deflateRect(rect),
          inputSize: Size(aspectRatioResult * 100, 100),
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
        Radius.circular(2.0),
      ),
    );
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: add another, smaller `RRect` to your `Path` - check `RRect` official documentation on how to do that